# Why does my object file show up as a dot?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, import, error

I completed a sculpt in the free open source 3d sculpting program Sculptris then exported it from Sculptris as a object.  but when I imported the object file into Blender  all I saw in the 3d view was a dot as the object. I do not know what do and have no idea what has caused this issue. I opened the mesh in windows 10 3d builder app and the mesh showed up normally but I am still unable to see it in Blender.  Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
I tried to scale the object to see if maybe the mesh was too big in the 3d view but I still saw nothing show up besides the dot. 
Here is a picture of what it looks like: 
[image: It's just a white dot!]

The object file I am trying to export is 24.8 MIB. If you want to know how big it is.  Please let me know if you know of a solution because I am so frustrated from this issue.

Here is the link to the blend file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/jpajin1epe8bvko/myobjectfile.blend

Comment: Can you upload your .blend somewhere? You can try http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ but I am not sure whether your file is not too big for that.

Comment: Yes, I tried to upload my blend file and it said that my file was too big.

Comment: Here is the link to the blend file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/jpajin1epe8bvko/myobjectfile.blend

Comment: The "Dot" is the Origin of your Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason and the solution is actually pretty simple, your model is just way too big and placed high (Z axis).
If you set the scene units to meters, it shows your figure is 5 kilometers tall :)

Just scale it down like this:
[image]

Comment: How do you open the transform window?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out.