# Why does my object file show up as an orange dot?

Tags: objects, import, error

I had imported a object file but I cannot see the object. It just show up a dot. I had tried to insert other object and it just showing a dot. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: I had saw this post: 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91643/why-does-my-object-file-show-up-as-a-dot?newreg=b690047664254f2db07ede5920f2925d

But the app version is not the same and I don't know where are the options as Iam a new user

Comment: Directly after import press N while over the 3d view to open the sidebar. On the item category, at the bottom the object dimensions are displayed. It is either too big as explained in link above, or too small. Scale accordingly.  The scale in SS suggests it is scaled way too small. The default cube has dimensions 2 x 2 x 2.  Pressing . on numeric keyboard will take you to object if it is no where near its origin.

Comment: (origin being  the orange dot)